# ".RestoreDirectory" does not work

Tags: c#, fileopendialog

In the following code I set `ofd1.RestoreDirectory` as `false` however, the dialog opens the inital directory everytime. Is there something that I am not aware of?

```
private void btnMeshFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd1.Title = "Open";
    ofd1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    ofd1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd1.FilterIndex = 2;
    ofd1.RestoreDirectory = false;
    if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(ofd1.FileName);
        MeshDirectoryPath = Path.GetFullPath(ofd1.FileName).Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        txtMeshFile.Text = fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the initial directory code?

Comment: Awesome. I should have put it as an answer lol ;p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From MSDN documentation of `RestoreDirectory`

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box restores the
>   current directory before closing.

So this property is about restoring `OS` current directory.

But you, in the code also use `InitialDirectory` property, forcing the dialog every time start from `@"c:\";` path. Remove this, and it will resolve your problem.

Comment: The same MSDN page, there is an example of how to restore the directory, but it uses also the property InitialDirectory. Is it a double-check or something?

Comment: @MaartenKesselaers: but in example we see RestoreDirectory=true, so what happens: OS Directory is (say): D:\, on opening dialog it shows C:\ (Initial directory porperty), OS Directory becomes C:\, after close of the dialog, as RestoreDirectory=true, OS Directory becomes D:\ again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now it seems more logic to me.